# Image cannot go full-width in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I want to make a screen with a full-width Android screen image, but however, for some reason I cannot do it. I have done every single solution available in SO but it still persists.

Here is my code:

```
<View style={styles.loginContainer}>
    <Image
        style={styles.background}
        source={require('./image.png')}
        //source={{uri: 'http://previews.123rf.com/images/background.jpg'}}
        opacity={0.8}
    >
    <Login navigator={navigator} />
    </Image>
</View>
```

and my Stylesheet:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
loginContainer: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch'
},
background: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch'
},
});
```

For some reason it worked just fine when I used network images, but when I used static images, it will only cover 2/3 width but full height. I have also tried source={{uri: 'image.png', isStatic: true}}, but it gives me null error. Any solution is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an [open issue on Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4598).

First of all, I would suggest using [the `resizeMode` property](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#resizemode), for instance:

```
<Image
  style={styles.background}
  source={require('./image.png')}
  opacity={0.8}
  resizeMode="contain"
>
```

Then, for network images, this would work:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  loginContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  background: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

For 'required' images, it does not work, as you pointed out, so you can either specify the width yourself:

```
var width = require('Dimensions').get('window').width;
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  loginContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  background: {
    flex: 1,
    width: width,
  },
});
```

Or even set it to `null`:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  loginContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  background: {
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
  },
});
```

Comment: Hi Almouro, this solution actually does the trick! However, I need to set the resizeMode as cover, instead of contain :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-scalable-image](https://github.com/ihor/react-native-scalable-image). The following example will give you a full screen width image:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Image from 'react-native-scalable-image';

const image = <Image width={Dimensions.get('window').width} source={{uri: '<image uri>'}} />;
```

Answer (score -1):

try this    `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view_full"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Rohit. Is ImageView native component or is it a plug-in?

Comment: It is native component